# Is there a way to add and play FLAC format?

Tags: music, audio

I searched through a lot Zune/Microsoft forums and people have been requesting this support for years but to no avail. Is there a work around? Is there a music player for Mango that can play FLAC format from OneDrive?

Answer (score 3):

Not to my knowledge, but you can use the free [foobar2000 audio player](http://www.foobar2000.org/) and [this guide](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=47759) to convert from FLAC to WMA Lossless to play on your WP7 device.

Another option is to mount a FLAC image (Surely you have matching .cue files for your .flac files) with [Daemons Tools](http://www.disc-tools.com/download/daemon) (free version perfectly suitable for the task) and ripping the virtual CD with WMP.

Answer (score 1):

Try [VLC For Windows Phone](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/VLC-for-Windows-Phone/9WZDNCRCV5TL). It plays `.flac` formats, and most media formats